# Group by Common Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I am trying to group values that are in common with each other, the idea is that for each letter that matches the first word then group them together.

The problem is that I cant add the additional matched values to the object.
I would like to know where I am going wrong.

```
var alphabet = ["A","B","W","D","H"];
var names = ["Ant","Water","Deer","Bee","Dog"];

var group = {};

for(var key in alphabet) {
    var value = alphabet[key];

    // console.log(value);
    // group[value] = "";

    for(var let in names){
        var letters = names[let];

        if(value == letters .substr(0, 1)){
            group[value] = letters;

            //console.log(letters);
        }
    }
}

console.log(group)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if(value == letters .substr(0, 1)){
// add empty array if not exists for that alphabate.......
if (!group[value]) {
     group[value] = [];
}
            group[value].push(letters);

            //console.log(letters);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you need to watch out for here.

The first is that you should never use `for/in` on an array, only objects (you can pick up non-numeric properties added to the array; also, it can iterate out-of-order; both problems that are hard to diagnose).

Secondly, `let` is a reserved word in JavaScript: it's not currently used, but it will be in ES6, and it has been in the "reserved for future use" category for a long time now.

How I would rewrite this:

```
var alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'W', 'D', 'H'];
var names = ['Ant', 'Water', 'Deer', 'Bee', 'Dog'];
var groups = {};

alphabet.forEach(function(letter){

    groups[letter] = [];

    names.forEach(function(name){
        if(name.substring(0,1)==letter){
            groups[letter].push(name);
        }
    });
});
```

This approach could result in empty groups (H, in this example).  If you want to avoid that, you could simply delete empty groups, or you could do this:

```
alphabet.forEach(function(letter){

    names.forEach(function(name){
        if(name.substring(0,1)==letter){
            if(!groups[letter]) groups.letter = [];
            groups[letter].push(name);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there really a need for the `alphabet` array here? Wouldn't it make more sense to determine what groups you need based on the values you have? Here's how you can do this:

```
var groups = {};

names.forEach(function(name) {
  var initial = name[0];
  if(!groups[initial]) {
    groups[initial] = [];
  }
  groups[initial].push(name);
});
```

Note that this has a running time complexity of O(N), whereas the nested `for`/`forEach` approach has O(M * N) running time. In other words, this is a lot more efficient than a nested `for`/`forEach` approach.

If you want to limit the available groups to those in `alphabet`, you can still do this efficiently, as follows:

```
var groups = {};

alphabet.forEach(function(group) {
  groups[group] = [];
}

names.forEach(function(name) {
  var initial = name[0], group = groups[initial];
  if(group) {
    group.push(name);
  }
});
```

Comment: @david Ok, in that case please see my second code sample (and please explain why the `alphabet` array is needed).

Answer (score 1):

What about this approach. Utilize constant time lookups with objects.

```
var names = {"ant":true, "water": true, "deer" : true, "bee": true, "dog": true};
var alphabet = {"a": true, "b": true, "w" : true, "d": true, "h": true}

var groups = {};

for(var key in names){
    var firstLetter = key[0];
    if(firstLetter in alphabet){
        groups[key] = firstLetter;
    }
}
```